# Strong IBOutlet nil in XIB with multiple views

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, xib, loadnibnamed

Calling `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed` to load a .xib file which contains (n) multiple variants of one UI defined with multiple `UIView`s instantiates n instances of my subclass.

I then apply a filter expression to choose the correct variant with `.first(where: { $0.restorationIdentifier == <correct restoration ID>`.

In this instance my filter expression correctly returns the 5th `UIView` inside of my .xib but the `@IBOutlet`s in my custom class are connected to the 1st `UIView` that was instantiated but which is immediately deprecated by what I assume is ARC.

This leads me to having unexpectedly nil `IBOutlet`s. What can be done to connect the `IBOutlet`s to the correct (5th in this case) UIView returned by `Bundle.main.loadNibBaned`

Comment: That wasn't my assumption. To the best of my knowledge ARC handles object cleanup/deletion and so it was my assumption that ARC is killing off all the instances of my custom class that my filter expression drops.

Comment: Oh yes, I misread the sentence. Yes, this makes sense, I'll delete my original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `loadNibNamed` is instantiating all your views, and you're only choosing to keep some of them around. In the process, IB outlets are assigned in some order, which most likely doesn't end up with your desired object being assigned to an outlet last.

I don't think a nib file gives you a way to instantiate only some of its multiple top level objects. You need to either split your various views into multiple nibs (and only load the one you need), or switch to using a Storyboard, which *does* let you instantiate specific objects by their identifier.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. In that case, what are the benefits of multiple UViews within one .xib? From your answer it seems that the benefits are somewhat limited.

Comment: Having multiple variants of a similar view in one "area" can be quite handy, for ensuring consistency, visualizing your app, and so on. Storyboards intentionally sought out to make this possible, where you can fish out and instantiate only specific view controllers, objects and such.

Comment: Okay thanks. I must be misunderstanding the difference between .xibs and .storyboards. I thought xibs are for defining smaller UIViews within view controllers and storyboards are  defining entire view controllers only. Best I can remember, last time I tried putting a free-form sized UIView within a storyboard, Xcode wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @pinglock An "entire view controller" doesn't actually mean much. Often people make the mistake of thinking that a view controller should define an entire screen or something, but really, any view could have its own controller, even something as small as a button.